# I am new to C. Second for loop is never ending why is it so

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float  n ,a, sum,count,count1;
    printf("\nInput integer in base 10 : ");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    for(count=0 ; count<=100 ; ++count){
        if(n/pow(2,count)<2 && n/pow(2,count)>=1)break;
    }
    a=n-pow(2,count);
    sum=pow(10,count);
    for(count1=count-1 ; count1>=0 ; --count){
        if(a/pow(2,count1)<2 && a/pow(2,count1)>=1 ){
            a-=pow(2,count1);
            sum+=pow(10,count1);
        }
    }
    printf("The binary of %.0f is %.0f",n,sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is for printing the binary equivalent of a decimal number without using arrays

Comment: How do you know it's the second loop that's the problem?

Comment: `--count` shouldn't it be `--count1`?

Comment: I know so because on executing the program it never reached the end. Printf statement after the 13th was giving the output which eliminated the first loop and a printf statement within the second for loop proved that it was never ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kiner_shah stated in a comment on your question, you have an incorrect variable being decremented in your second loop.

```
for(count1=count-1 ; count1>=0 ; --count){
    ...
```

should be

```
for(count1=count-1 ; count1>=0 ; --count1){
    ...
```

Using more distinct / descriptive variable names to avoid single character mistakes is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was irritating me for sometime.....will use distinct variables from now on